# How do I pass an image in dynamically in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have the following code:

```
let fileIcon = props.type == DOCUMENT_TYPE.Project ? "024-folder-16" : "file";
let concatString = '../assets/images/'.concat(fileIcon, 'png');
```

and I'm trying to use the value "concatString" later on:

```
let fileIcon = props.type == DOCUMENT_TYPE.Project ? "024-folder-16" : "file";
let concatString = '../assets/images/'.concat(fileIcon, 'png');

const renderChapterItem = chapterData => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity 
            style={styles.gridItem} 
            onPress={() => { 
                props.navigation.navigate("Document", {text: chapterData.item[1]})
            }}
        >
            <Image
                style={styles.image}
                source={require(concatString)}/>
    )
}
```

However, I keep getting an error

> Invalid call at line 21: require(concatString)

Comment: Why are you using require? Where in your code do you do the image source logic and where is the Image tag?

Comment: edited my question to add more code

Comment: just use concatString variable without require if it is located within the same file. Might need to add this as a prefix.

Comment: I removed "require" and I'm not getting the error anymore but now no image is loading

Answer (score 1):

let concatString = '../assets/images/'.concat(fileIcon, '.png');
Replace your concatString with the above given variable. You haven't added "." before the extention "png".

Another option:

Import both your images separately, and use them rather require statement.
like :

```
import img1 from '../../{YOUR_IMAGE_NAME_WITH_EXTENTION}';

import img2 from '../../{YOUR_IMAGE_NAME_WITH_EXTENTION}';


let img = (condition)? img1 : img2;


            <Image
                style={styles.image}
                source={img}/>
```